# HTML saving to PDF loses anchor tags

Tags: html, pdf, browser

I created an HTML page with a my own styles. I also customized bootstrap to remove the print media styles on my downloads. Yet I still lose anchor tags in the PDF that is saved, as if the `href` attribute doesn't exist, there are no links to follow. I tried to save the HTML to PDF in Chrome, Firefox and Opera all didn't work.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here is part of the code.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cv-style.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/bootstrap-no-print-media/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="all">

</head>

<body class="container">
<header id="name">
    <h1 id="my-name">Sime Habtu</h1>
    <article>
        <div id="online">            
            <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/3597111/sime" target="rss"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow fa-lg"></i></a>            
        </div>
    </article>
</header>
</body>
```

So here when I save the outcome of this code to PDF I get the style and content but the links are not there. The stackoverflow icon here won't print with the embedded link.

Comment: You have any code available?

Comment: In the edit I added some part of the code. do you mean something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out why the links were not working. Hopefully someone will find this helpful.
It turns out the problem was caused by the google fonts that was added using the `@import` in the CSS. When the google fonts were used by linking them in the HTML file the anchor tags were working on the converted PDF file.